# Saiku implementaion on Openshift and mysql connect issue

Tags: mysql, openshift, saiku

I am implementing a saiku server on openshift platform. How to connect to a mysql database on openshift for a saiku application.

Demo configuration

```
<i> type=OLAP </i>
<i>name=foodmart </i>
<i>driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver </i>
<i>location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:hsqldb:res:foodmart/foodmart;Catalog=res:foodmart/FoodMart.xml; </i>
<i>username=sa </i>
<i>password= </i>
```

How to use mysql environment variables in the above config

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [wiki.meteorite.bi](http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Data+Sources)

> Data Source Definition
>
> All data sources are stored as plain text files in folder
>   saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/saiku-datasources/
>   with one data source per file. You can use your favourite text editor
>   to add/edit data source. This is how sample data source for MySQL
>   looks like:
>
> type=OLAP
>
> name=steelwheels
>
> driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
>
> location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledata;Catalog=res:foodmart/Foodmart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
>
> username=dbuser
>
> password=password
>
> Every data source definition contains at least the following elements:
>
> type - Always OLAP.
>
> name - Name of data source. This name will be shown to Saiku user
>   together with schema name.  Can contain spaces.
>
> driver - Driver for specific database. See examples below to find
>   correct driver for your data.
>
> location - Location of data and Mondrian schema (see Location
>   Details).
>
> username - Username to be used when connecting to data source.
>
> password - Password to be used when connecting to data source.

You can also visit this [page](http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Adding+a+new+data+source)